# Choose only one location in google maps api, and accessing argument in next page

Tags: google-maps

The title says the question. Now, is it good to use a counter that starts from zero and when it is 1 or more I wouldn't add a marker. Or should I try to make it such that when someone clicks on the map the old marker disappears and the new one is assigned? The following code is what I have so far.. Thanks for any kind of help.

Also, how can I access the longitude and latitude in the next page?

And about capturing the map into a blob, is it a different topic or it is also related?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Accessing arguments in UI events</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
  });
}

function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
  map.panTo(position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize();">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say its up to you and your application later how you handle the markers.

You can implement a counter, create a dragable marker, depends how the app will work later on.

How will your next page look like?

---

One simple way could be something like this:

I use addListenerOnce to call the placeMarker function only one time and during this i write the latitude and longitude in a form field.

now you can add action parameters plus a submit button and you can access the values on your next page.

Thats the fiddle + code:
http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/LcKy2/

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 4,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'click', function(e) {
    placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
   // alert(e.latLng.toString());
    document.getElementById("latitude").value = e.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("longitude").value = e.latLng.lng(); 
  });
}

function placeMarker(position, map) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map
  });
  map.panTo(position);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```